# How can i define a primary foreign key in Toad for Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle11g, ddl

How can i define a primary foreign key(PFK) in Toad for Oracle ?

Comment: Did you Google for some [reference](http://www.toadworld.com/KNOWLEDGE/KnowledgeXpertforOracle/tabid/648/TopicID/POP6D/Default.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a foreign key under constraints after you have set up the table.
[a link to a picture of the constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmdpu.png)

Comment: i know how to add a foreign key but i want to add a primary foreign key, how can i do this ?

Comment: http://objectmix.com/php/347409-diference-betwen-foreign-key-primary-foreign-key.html   Try this page.  It uses direct sql statements, but I think it will accomplish what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you, i figured out how to solve it.